# What is the relationship between spiritual path, sectarian affiliation, and ascetic mode?

Tags: yoga, spiritual-level

What is the relationship between **spiritual** path, **sectarian**
**affiliation**, and **ascetic** mode?

Comment: IMHO Spiritual path means that you accept your path as true, but you also accept others path as true. For example you say 'I am a Bhakti Yogi, but I also accept Jnana Yoga as valid path'. However sectarian affiliation means that you accept only your sect as true and other sects as invalid. You think 'I am a member of Xism, all Yists are wasting their time, because it is invalid'. Not only thinking that but telling it to others is even worse!! That is sectarian affiliation.

Comment: What do you mean by ascetic mode?

Comment: it mean Tapsvi mode,

Answer (score 3):

Cannot be described perfectly as you request as these are not exactly defined terms.

The easiest is sectarian affiliation, which simply means which sect do you identify with or belong to.

Spiritual path is a vague term, not used or defined in scripture. It can mean mean many things. Sometimes the religion you follow, or sect you belong to, or yoga methods you do, or philosophical school, or a combination, or other things as well.

Tapasya are the spiritual practices that you do to purify your mind to help you realize God. Again in general it is those things you do to control your mind and senses. It can mean many things in practice and what may be tapasya for you may not be tapasya for another person.. Practicing meditation is tapasya. Practicing silence is also. Fasting is tapasya. Japam is tapasya. The same general tapasyas are practiced across different sects and different religions.